# Vuforia Installation on Windows 8

Tags: android, sdk, android-ndk, vuforia

I have successfully installed Android SDK and NDK in order to be able to install Vuforia on Windows 8, but nevertheless I cannot install it.The displaying message when I try to install Vuforia is :

"Installer User Interface Mode Not Supported. The installer cannot run in this UI mode. To specify the interface mode, use the -i command-line option, followed by the UI mode identifier. The valid UI modes identifiers are GUI, Console, and Silent."

Do you know whether Vuforia is compatible to Windows 8 or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/sdk/android v2.0.31 Known Issues](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/sdk/android)

On Windows 8, the installer needs to be run in Windows 7 compatibility mode:

1. Right-mouse click on the installer executable
2. Select Properties
3. Select the Compatibility tab
4. Check the box for "Run this program in compatibility mode for:", and select "Windows 7"

Comment: Thank you very much.The problem solved one minute after your help.